# Creating email forwarding accounts on the fly using PHP

Tags: php, email

I was wondering if it was possible to create email forwading accounts on the fly as I have created subdomains for uses profiles i.e. user.profile.com and was wondering if I could create user@profile.com to forward to their email account?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but the solution consists of 2 parts:

1. Ask on the serverfault **what** operations you have have to perform. what config file to edit or something.
2. Then ask here on SO, how to automate these basic operations (file open, write, etc) using PHP.